# How to send 'Some' with argument in a function

Tags: rust

I am trying to send the result of a match to a function `Foo`, but the result of the match is type `Some()`

How can I send it as an argument to the `Foo` function?

```
struct Person {
    name: Option<String>,
    lastname: Option<String>,
}

fn Foo(x: Option<String>) {
    println!("{:?}", x);
}

fn main() {
    let name = "Steve".to_string();
    let lastname = "Alvarez".to_string();
    let mut x: Option<Person> = Some(Person {
        name: Some(name),
        lastname: Some(lastname),
    });

    match x {
        Some(Person {
            name: ref a @ Some(_),
            lastname: ref b @ _,
        }) => Foo(a),
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, fields and modules; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants.

Answer (score 2):

## Step 1

First, your `match x { Some(Person{...})...` looks wrong. Unwrap it as `Some(person) => foo(person.name)`.

```rust
struct Person {
    name: Option<String>,
    lastname: Option<String>,
}

fn foo(x: Option<String>) {
    println!("{:?}", x);
}

fn main() {
    let name = "Steve".to_string();
    let lastname = "Alvarez".to_string();
    let x: Option<Person> = Some(Person {
        name: Some(name),
        lastname: Some(lastname),
    });

    match x {
        Some(person) => foo(person.name),
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

## Step 2: Make it nicer

Taking an `Option` as a function argument is not very Rust-like, I believe. (I might be wrong, since I am new to Rust as well.)

Also, the `match` where the `None` option is not taken is also an antipattern, I believe. Instead, use a [combinator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/option_unwrap/and_then.html) (`map` or `and_then`).

```rust
struct Person {
    name: Option<String>,
    lastname: Option<String>,
}

fn foo(x: String) {
    println!("{:}", x);
}

fn main() {
    let name = "Steve".to_string();
    let lastname = "Alvarez".to_string();
    let x: Option<Person> = Some(Person {
        name: Some(name),
        lastname: Some(lastname),
    });

    x.and_then(|person| person.name) // person.name is an Option -> thus use `and_then`
        .map(|n| foo(n));
}
```

[Live Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1079305c557fc3797cef8c49dd7c7ef5)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, Rust has a somewhat complex learning curve and is costing me a little

Comment: *Taking an `Option` as a function argument is not very Rust-like* — it's perfectly fine in certain cases, and completely the wrong thing in others.

Comment: I'm updating my question. With a cleaner approach

Comment: @Shepmaster I've updated it. In this case, IMO taking is an foo taking an Option is not clean. What is the function to do with an option.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with "cleanliness", it has to do with the semantics of the program. Sometimes you need to know that there isn't a value and sometimes you don't care.

Comment: @Shepmaster I realize that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the existing code is that `Foo` consumes an `Option`, while your match gets a reference to an `Option`. They need to match. There's a few approaches that will work here.

1. Make `Foo` and the match both use values. This means you remove the `ref` on the match pieces. You wont be able to use the `Person` value after the match, since it will have been chopped into its component pieces.

```
fn Foo(x: Option<String>) {
    println!("{:?}", x);
}

// ... 

    match x {
        Some(Person {
            name: a @ Some(_),
            lastname: b @ _,
        }) => Foo(a),
        _ => {}
    }
```

2. Make `Foo` and the match both use references. You keep the ref on the match, but add an `&` to `Foo`'s argument.

```
fn Foo(x: &Option<String>) {
    println!("{:?}", x);
}

// ... 

    match x {
        Some(Person {
            name: ref a @ Some(_),
            lastname: ref b @ _,
        }) => Foo(a),
        _ => {}
    }
```

3. Clone `a` before passing it to `Foo`. `Foo` and the match pattern don't change, but the way you call `Foo` changes slightly

```
fn Foo(x: Option<String>) {
    println!("{:?}", x);
}

// ... 

    match x {
        Some(Person {
            name: ref a @ Some(_),
            lastname: ref b @ _,
        }) => Foo(a.clone()),
        _ => {}
    }
```

Of course, in your particular case you dont need to use pattern matching at all, you could just use some of the tools that already exist in `Option`, such as `map`.

```
x.map(|p| Foo(p.name));
```